# Linux: Mathematica crashes when clicking documentation links very fast

Tags: front-end, bugs, crash

**Bug introduced in 10.0.1 or earlier and fixed in 10.1.0**

---

Can someone confirm the following behavior: Open a new Mathematica and go to the documentation. Navigate to any reference page (I used `RegionPlot`) and click repeatedly and very fast the `RegionPlot` link in one of the usages.

After a short time (sometimes maybe a bit longer) *Mathematica* crashes. I have made a screen-cast of this:

[image: graphics]
<sub>(source: [ytimg.com](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/7NwCc3CDuzg/2.jpg))</sub>

My system is:

- Ubuntu 14.04
- Mathematica 10.0.2

Comment: Same on Fedora 21, v10.0.1. But I need to click like 15 times before it crashes.

Comment: @Öskå It's the same here. Sometimes it crashes after only a few clicks and sometimes I need 50 clicks. But it always crashes. One time, the front end froze without crashing but I had to kill the session.

Comment: For 32 bit ubuntu 10.04 version Mma v10.0.1 I had to click more that 40 times. Sometimes frontend don't crash, however occupies 100% cpu and no response.

Comment: I also have this happen on occasion (and I'm also on Ubuntu).

Comment: Same problem on Linux Mint.

Comment: The work around is to click slower :p

Comment: @AndyRoss You could post that as an answer. I'd upvote it heartily! :D

Comment: It also crashes for me (Ubuntu 14.04) and gives the error message: "Mathematica has received the signal: SIGSEGV and has exited." This happens frequently after working for an extended period of time and clicking a link in the help section.

Comment: M10.0.2 Debian 7 with OpenBox windowmanager also gets crashed after around 40 fast clicks.

Comment: No problem (within 100 clicks) on OS X 10.10.1, or I'm not clicking fast enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<sup>(Reposting my comment as an answer to take the question off the unanswered list).</sup>

This Linux-specific crash has been fixed as of version 10.1.0.